# How to use multiif in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I couldn't find any functions similar to multiif in postgresql. In clickhouse documentation it says multiif is similar to CASE. Can somebody tell me how to use CASE in postgresql to realize multiif's function?

Comment: It is Case when .... then .... when .... then ... else ... end.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: [CASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)

Comment: Please augment your question by explaining what **multiif function is**.